# Possible to share iOS App Groups between an Enterprise team and a standard team?

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-sandbox, ios-app-group, enterprise-distribution

Apple offers a few different account types. Standard at $100/year and Enterprise at $300 /year.

I have both, and want to share information between the deployed apps, perhaps using App Groups.

Is this possible in iOS ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not possible, because app groups are only shared within a single development team.

> The com.apple.security.application-groups (available in OS X v10.7.5 and v10.8.3 and later) allows multiple apps produced by **a single development team** to share access to a special group container.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/EnablingAppSandbox.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011195-CH4-SW19